# Reset Highest unique bid Auction EndDate on Server side

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

Currently I am working on Highest unique bid Auction site (ASP.NET MVC). Auctions have end date, using the jQuery countdown plugin as timer. Once the timer reaches zero and still bid quota is left then on jQuery countdown expiry event, using ajax call updating the end date to "end date + some duration".

But if the browser is not open. And the current end date of a auction elapses,

How should I update the end date in this scenario.

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you maintaining the auction end date and quota in database ? Using jQuery timer, to keep track of expiration time is not a good choice. You should handle this scenario with a separate background thread in your application, which kicks of, once the application starts. It should be the responsibility of this thread to update the quota or expiration time. Then from UI, you just query the auction status from database and keep the front end updated.

Comment: yeah i have the end date and the quota in database. currently every time a bid is posted i am decreasing the quota to one and updating the same on auction.

Comment: Could you please give more details how this separate background thread should work . i mean does this need to be run every sec or what ?

Comment: You can either use a thread or Timer, and periodically check if the auction time has expired but the quota is still available. If yes, then the logic of updating the expiration time should be handled in this thread. All I am emphasizing is that, do not use, jQuery or javascript(setTimeOut) feature for keeping track of these information. Moreover, jQuery is a client side operation. You do not want to expose, such critical aspect of business as a client side operation. Even moderately experienced web developer, can easily change the behavior.